# syntax error near unexpected token `('-------My program compiled well but can't run

Tags: c

Here is the running time error:

```
    @user:~/workspace$ gcc compute.c
    compute.c: In function ‘main’:
    compute.c:59:1: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     ^
    compute.c:59:1: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
     user:~/workspace$ gcc compute.c -std=c99
l    user:~/workspace$ ./compute.c
    ./compute.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    ./compute.c: line 3: `int main()'
```

I don't know how to fix it.I think my code is OK.

When I compile it,it's perfect, but it just doesn't work when I run it.

Here is my Code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  typedef struct{
    float real;
    float virtual;
  }component;

  component construtor(int real, int virtual) {
    component c;
    c.real=real;
    c.virtual=virtual;
    return c;
  }

  component add(component c1, component c2){
     component new;
     new.real=c1.real+c2.real;
     new.virtual=c1.virtual+c2.virtual;
     return new;
  }

  component minus(component c1, component c2){
    component new;
    new.real=c1.real-c2.real;
    new.virtual=c1.virtual-c2.virtual;
    return new;
  }

  component multiply(component c1, component c2){
    component new;
    new.real=c1.real*c2.real-c1.virtual*c2.virtual;
    new.virtual=c1.real*c2.virtual+c1.virtual*c2.real;
    return new;
   }

  float real(component c){
    return c.real;
  }

  float virtual(component c){
    return c.virtual;
  }

   component division(component c1, component c2){
    component new;
    new.real =     (c1.real*c2.real+c1.virtual*c2.virtual)/(c2.real*c2.real+c2.virtual*c2.virtual);
new.virtual = (c1.virtual*c2.real-c1.real*c2.virtual)/(c2.real*c2.real+c2.virtual*c2.virtual);
    return new;
   }

  component conjugate(component c){
    c.virtual=(-1)*c.virtual;
    return c;
}

component test_data[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
  scanf("enter the real part: %f\n",&test_data[i].real);
  scanf("enter the virtual part: %f\n",&test_data[i].virtual);
 }

  component add_result=add(test_data[0],test_data[1]);
  component minus_result=minus(test_data[2],test_data[3]);
  component multiply_result=multiply(test_data[4],test_data[5]);
  component division_result=division(test_data[6],test_data[7]);
  component conjugate_result=conjugate(test_data[8]);

  printf("Add two components: %f+%f i",real(add_result),virtual(add_result));
  printf("Minus two components: %f+%f i", real(minus_result),virtual(minus_result));
  printf("Multiply two components: %f+%f i",     real(multiply_result),virtual(multiply_result));
  printf("Division two components: %f+%f i",     real(division_result),virtual(division_result));
  printf("Conjugate of a components: %f+%f i",   real(conjugate_result),virtual(conjugate_result));

  return 0;
}
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: _When I compile it,it's perfect_ : the compiler disagrees with you.

Comment: Do as the friendly compiler tells you: "note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code".

Comment: @mah I compiler it perfectly too but it can't run.Please try run it .

Comment: @Lundin It's not that problem.Please try to run it and you will konw the error.It's a running time error.

Comment: You should run the output from the compiler, not the file with the source code. Your output from above compilation is properbly a.out

Comment: @luojiebin I don't know what you're actually doing, only what you think your doing, and from what you've shown, a) your compiler is failing to produce anything that could run (you are _not_ compiling it "perfectly", if you were, there would not be a syntax error!), and b) you are not yet at a state where you can say it fails to run since it fails to compile.

Comment: `./compute.c` --> `./a.out`

Comment: @luojiebin: Please get a good C book or follow a tutorial. The above code, which has so many functions _defined_ inside the `main` function is super wrong!

Comment: @mah  It has a compile error because I forget -std=c99 at the first time.Problem has solved.I should type "./a.out" in my terminal instead of "./compute.What a fool I am.Anyway,thanks.

Comment: Which compiler allows function declarations inside functions?

Comment: @luojiebin if you add `-o compute` to your compile line, then `./compute` will run it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a compiler which does not support declarations in `for` loop or you are missing a switch:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
```

Do this:

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){ //....
```

Going by your comments you can't *run* a `.c` file, you have to *compile* it first and i think you are getting the syntax wrong.

Do this `gcc -Wall yourFile.c -o yourFile -std=C99` to compile it (or, more simply, `make yourFile`). Then you can `./ex1` to run the program.

Comment: user:~/workspace$ ./compute.c
    ./compute.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    ./compute.c: line 3: `int main()'

Comment: @luojiebin _It's a running time error.see above_ **NO**, it's not. This is a really basic point that you're not understanding and until you understand it, you're going to remain doomed as a programmer. Fortunately it's really simple to understand, but you have to first be willing -- so stop insisting otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

By default, with out any options passed, GCC would assume *gnu90* (which C90 + GNU extensions) as the C standard; C90 doesn't allow variable declarations in the middle of a function (declaring an `int` inside the `for` is also a variation of this); all declarations should preceed other statements. However, this rule was changed with C99 standard and like C++ declarations can be made anywhere in a function (with some exceptions).

Since you're not specifiying it's C99 or the C11, the compiler falls back to C90 and compains about it. You can either move the declaration to the top, or tell the compiler that you follow a later standard.